# Test one specific test suite given a cunit test file

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, suite, cunit

Given a cunit test containing multiple suites (Suite1, Suite2, Suite3) which I can run all at once with "./test" How do I test one specific suite (Suite2) in that cunit file?

I tried "./test Suite2" which didn't work, and the cunit website seems seriously lackluster on the options on running cunit tests

Comment: Do you mean passing arguments to program in order to execute different tasks, based on passed value?

Comment: I guess that;s one way to do it. For some reason I thought there would be a built-in way to select suites for testing. Maybe the GUI has this feature.

Comment: I meant passing arguments in command line.. by the way in C it can be done by using argv and argc take a look here: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html